# Booting Ubuntu from USB, how can I remove its ability to mess with the hard drive?

Tags: ubuntu, usb

I have installed Ubuntu on a USB drive to create myself a sandbox environment away from my normal computer.

Ubuntu can browse the contents of my normal hard drive however, which I don't like.

How can I remove its ability to find/mount/read the hard drive?

Is there a hard drive driver that I could uninstall?

Comment: Can't you just unmount the hard drive after booting?

Comment: It is unmounted. This question is just an exercise in paranoia. If Ubuntu is compromised I want to make it as hard as possible to find my other files.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the model of your motherboard, you can disable the hard drive in the *BIOS*.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows file systems are usually loadable modules.  You could blacklist then and remove them from the lib directory.  This would make accessing the file system more difficult.

Unix/Linux disk access is required to access the USB drive.  If you don't have one you don't have the other.  The I/O routines are pretty common across all devices, so there is likely little that can be removed without breaking I/O significantly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are that concerned, consider removing the sata data cable from the hard disk. Then you can do whatever you want software-side, you can't access or modify the data.